# How to select only string between some certain values in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I use Teradata SQL and I have table liek below:

```
col1
-------------
LN1: aaabbcc|LN2:...
LN1: rrtt|LN2:....
```

And I would like to take only values from "col1" which are between LN1: and |LN2:..... How can I take it in Teradata SQL ?

as a result I need:

```
col1
-----------
aaabbcc
rrtt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teradata supports a function to extract this info from name/value pairs:

[NVP](https://docs.teradata.com/r/nBGHhgDQeL0nr8iz78FuXg/iocve5wbsYYuMNxrkWAHdw)

```
NVP(col1, 'LN1', '|', ':')
```

To get rid of the leading space you might add TRIM.